# Retain subscript when converting to .eps

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, eps

My subscripts in the axis *tick* label get messed up when I create an .eps-file.

I have created subscripted axis-tick labels for my figure by adding e.g. char(8321) to my axis tick label strings. Everything works fine and the subscript appears in the .fig file. When I convert the file to .eps they are replaced by something that looks like "a[][]". Any way to fix?

Comment: have you tried export_fig from fileexchange?

Comment: Alternative thing to try, use LaTeX for the labels.

Comment: maybe try `xlabel(...,'Interpreter','none')` or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have now clarified a mistake in my OP. The error appears in the axis _tick_ labels. Unfortunately I am not allowed to install the ghostscrip necessary to run export_fig on this computer.